# Validate text input by comparing it to an array of strings

Tags: android

I want to be able to take an users input from a text field and then compare if it exists in a string array. Something simple for right now such as asking the user "Spell dog" and then they use input the text in a text field and then once they are done it compares it to the word dog. I can preset them or use an inbuilt dictionary, some research says I would use EditView and change it from there, but I cannot think of anyway to do so and all the other example I found do not quite answer it. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: pick one of those examles you looked at and understand, and start to work with it. After you tried to do it post your code here in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this can help you:
You can use a hash like this

```
    HashMap<String,String> mData;
    mData.put("dog","...");
    ...
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

           @Override
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           if (mData.containsKey(editText1.getText().toString()))
             // success code
           }

           @Override
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

           }

           @Override    
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
             int count, int after) {
           }

      });
```